# Disk Crashed, NDF(Index) file lost

Tags: sql-server, restore, disaster-recovery

I have database with :

-two filegroups (PRIMARY and INDEX)

-three files .mdf(data), .ndf(index) and .ldf(log)

every file is on different disk, yesterday disk where was NDF file crashed so I lost that file.
Is there any way to fix database, without restore?

TNX!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there any way to fix database, without restore?

No, you will have to do a restore.  Please see this reference on [how to do file and filegroup restores](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178099(v=SQL.105).aspx).

Comment: TNX.

Please, let me ask you one more question.

I have only FULL and LOG backups.

Is there any way to restore only NDF file with FULL backup file?

Comment: Yes, do you file/filegroup restore using the full backup with `NORECOVERY`, and then restore your log backups sequentially, with the last one specifying `RECOVERY`.  The link I posted in my answer shows how all of that can be accomplished.

Comment: I understand restore procedure, I was just not sure about restoring only one file(in this case index file). It is great to know that it is possible.
Thank you! :)